# Error 500 on wordpress install LEMP server

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I just finished setting up a new linode with Nginx and ISPconfig as per howtoforge's instructions, and when I go to setup my new wordpress site www.timberwright.net I get error 500.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Did you install wordpress using the APS installer that comes with ISPConfig 3, or did you do it manually?

Comment: manually, I wasn't aware of APS...

Comment: Under the Sites tab on the left menu look for APS Installer. Click Update Packagelist, on this page click the Update Packagelist Button. This might take some time to complete, once its done you can then install Wordpress by clicking on Available Packages and typing in the Name field "Wordpress" then press the enter key. From there you should be okay. Also I personally would delete the current site and re-add it once you have the APS packages available.

Comment: is there a repo I need to add for this to work?

Comment: No extra repos needed, it fetches an xml file that shows it where to get the files from. Once you have update your packagelist you will see the available packages under Available Packages.

Comment: alright, that fixed it!

On another note, why can we not just upload the files like normal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26208/discussion-between-steven-farley-and-jonyork)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the aps system, as mentioned in the comments above I was able to setup my wordpress site no fuss no muss with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, with nginx and ISPconfig 3